# Java FileReader method is not returning/printing all characters in file record

Tags: java

I am trying to write to a file thru FileWriter and then read it thru FileReader. FileWriter writes the record to file okay, but the FileReader method appears to be skipping characters while printing. I have pasted the code and the file contents and output below. Can you please help identify what I might be missing or doing wrong?

***Update -
Just realized a possibility (after posting) that the "read()" in the while statement could be reading a Character ahead the "read()" in the print statement, and hence causing every other character (beginning with the first one) to skip the print statement. Not sure though. Could that be what is happening here?

### Code  -

```
public class FileIOCharClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File TestChar = new File("C:\\TestChar.txt");
        FileIOCharClass FileIOChar = new FileIOCharClass();
        try {
            FileIOChar.charWriteMethod(TestChar);
        }
        catch (IOException a){
            System.out.println("IO Exception occured in Write method");
        }
        try{
            FileIOChar.charReadMethod(TestChar);
        }
        catch (IOException b){
            System.out.println("IO Exception occured in Read method");
        }
    }

    private void charWriteMethod(File CharFileToWrite) throws IOException {
        FileWriter WriteRoutine = null;
        try{
            WriteRoutine = new FileWriter(CharFileToWrite);
            WriteRoutine.write("Line-1");
            WriteRoutine.write("Line-2");
            WriteRoutine.write("Line-3");
        }finally {
            WriteRoutine.flush();
            WriteRoutine.close();
        }

    }

    private void charReadMethod(File CharFileToRead) throws IOException {
        FileReader ReadRoutine = new FileReader(CharFileToRead);
        while (ReadRoutine.read() != -1){
            System.out.println(((char)ReadRoutine.read()));
        }
    }
}
```

### Contents of TestChar file created -

```
Line-1Line-2Line-3
```

### Program print output

```
i
e
1
i
e
2
i
e
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You are reading and throwing away every odd character. Reconsider yur read loop. You need one read, and a variable.

Comment: Just a simple programming mistake. No worries. Nothing wrong with the ``FileReader``. When checking ``ReadRoutine.read() != -1`` you read a character which you then never print out. Then you read the ___next___ character in ``System.out.println(((char)ReadRoutine.read()));`` and print it out. And and so on. That's why your implementation doesn't print out the complete contents of your test file – or just only every other character.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are reading twice. Once int the while condition, and another in the block statement

```
        while (ReadRoutine.read() != -1){
            System.out.println(((char)ReadRoutine.read()));
        }
```

Instead you can try:

```
int data = ReadRoutine.read();
while (data != -1) {
    System.out.println((char)data);
    data = ReadRoutine.read();
}
```